# how calculate video file size by formula

Tags: math, video, calculator, video-processing

I want to compress video in Android and upload it. before compressing I want to show the deferent width and height and estimated Size then user chooses one.

```
 for example:
    240  estimated Size =~20 MB
    480  estimated Size =~40 MB
    640  estimated Size =~90 MB
    720  estimated Size =~130 MB
    1080 estimated Size =~180 MB
```

now I look for a formula for calculating estimated size.
I get width and height and bitrate from MediaMetadataRetriever in Android

```
 retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
 retriever.setDataSource(path, new HashMap<String, String>());
 width = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH);
 height = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT);
 rotation = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION);
```

Comment: Size = bitrate x duration. Resolution doesn’t matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it.
for calculating file size from Bit rate and duration we can use:

```
(bitrate() / 8 * duration() / 1000/1000)
```

for example

```
file size=((17305731/8)*(4655000/1000/1000))=‭10,069,772‬= 9.6 MB
```

Comment: Great answer, and yes its working